# variable parsing issue - Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Hi All,

When I do console.log(optValues), it gives me the syntax as show above.
If I'm trying parse as `optValues[0]` it's giving me as `undefined`.

But `typeof optValues` is returning as `object`.  I'm not getting how do I read the values here. Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: did you try $.parseJSON and then indexing it?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet? Didn't actually catch how you are trying to parse.

Comment: @Furquan parseJSON is not working

Comment: @Samuil it's just a 2 line function I'm getting that data as function  parameter.